# SwiftUI Table scroll not fluency more than 5 columns

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

on the macOS 12, When the columns less than 5, scroll is fluency,the cpu usage low than 100%. more than 5 columns scroll is not fluency, the cpu usage is always over 100%.how can I resolve this problem?

[image: 1 columns scroll]
[image: 9 columns scroll]
here is my code:

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = String(Int.random(in: 0...5000))
    var id2 = String(Int.random(in: 0...5000))
    var id3 = String(Int.random(in: 0...5000))
    var id4 = String(Int.random(in: 0...5000))
    var id5 = String(Int.random(in: 0...5000))
    var id6 = String(Int.random(in: 0...5000))
    var id7 = String(Int.random(in: 0...5000))
    var id8 = String(Int.random(in: 0...5000))
    var id9 = String(Int.random(in: 0...5000))
}

struct ContentView3: View {
    @State var items = [Item]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Update") {
                prepareData()
            }
            
            Table(items) {
                TableColumn("id1", value: \.id)
                TableColumn("id2", value: \.id2)
                TableColumn("id3", value: \.id3)
                TableColumn("id4", value: \.id4)
                TableColumn("id5", value: \.id5)
                TableColumn("id6", value: \.id6)
                TableColumn("id7", value: \.id7)
                TableColumn("id8", value: \.id8)
                TableColumn("id9", value: \.id9)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 800, height: 600)
    }
    
    func prepareData() {
        var list = [Item]()
        for _ in 1...2000 {
            let item = Item()
            list.append(item)
        }
        items = list
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `item`. Please provide a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I update my code in question description,thank you!

Comment: Yes I can see some lag too the larger the table becomes. This seems natural, as a couple of 100 of cells are redrawn. I suppose there is nothing you can do about it.